# Redirect to another view django

Tags: django, django-views

I want to redirect to anothe view if validate_token method return false but when i do like the code below it does not redierct me to the other app context it just return a html page without django templating

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'token' in request.session:
        if model.validate_token():
            return render(request, "home.html", {})
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html", {})
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html", {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by
import render, redirect, reverse
after that return `redirect(reverse('replace with url'))`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'token' in request.session:
        if model.validate_token():
            return render(request, "home.html", {})
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('login'))
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('login'))
```